# volume discount for unique customized product

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, custom-options, discount, tierprice

In my shop (magento 1.7.0.2) customers can order cardboard cutouts with a personalized design (by uploading their picture).

I want to implement a volume discount per uniquely customized product.
For example: the customer orders 
5 pieces of the product with his own picture A, and
1 piece of THE SAME product but with his own picture B
=>  then the volume discount should apply only to the 5 pieces with picture A

(reasoning behind it is, as you probably guessed, that making one piece is expensive but making a duplicate is relatively cheap).

The products are simple products with a custom option (i.c. the uploaded picture file).

How can you create such a volume pricing?

Comment: you´re talking about Tier pricing?

Answer (score 3):

Tier Pricing is a promotional tool that allows a store owner to price items differently for higher quantities.When a customer adds a certain quantity of a product to their cart, the price is automatically changed to reflect the discount.
In the Magento Admin Panel, navigate to Catalog > Manage Products.
Locate the Prices tab for a product  button that says Add Tier and then customise your tier price.

Comment: Gasp... Yes. That works. So simple. I imagined the tier pricing would not work because it's multiple instances of the same product. But it does. Thanks very much!

Comment: Mabybe someone can vote this as the right answer